Western movie where criminal mastermind appears to be a begger
I am looking for the title of a Western where a large and elegant stagecoach is on its way through the American West, and is stopped by a dirty, ragged beggar.
The beggar goes to the stagecoach  and occupies a site under the eyes of the elegant and wealthy passengers of it. Two passengers initiate a conversation about the beggar's appearance and he shows its ignorance, misery and ignorance of the reality that surrounds him. These people use an academic and intellectual language, to ensure that the beggar does not understand what is being discussed, much less feels offended. The beggar just listens and listens... listens...and begins to speak and respond with an unusual mastery of language for a beggar...
The beggar was not such. It was nothing but one of the most astute and intelligent criminals of the American West, and only posing as a beggar and then storms the stagecoach with gang.
The scene contains some interesting dialogues, I know some clue to the title of this movie and view it completely.

"I know some clue to the title of this movie" - Can you also add that clue to the question if you know it?

I tried to rephrase your question and improve it as much as I felt possible and understood from it. Feel free to revert it if that is not what you were trying to say.

I would have to check as its been a while since I've seen it, but for some reason in my mind's eye I'm seeing Russell Crowe in 3:10 to Yuma.

You are looking for Giù La Testa directed by Sergio Leone starring Rod Steiger and James Coburn, original score by Ennio Morricone.
Poster http://m2.paperblog.com/i/77/778649/giu-la-testa-L-se0KAP.jpeg
The scene you quoted is the following one, right at the beginning of the film:


 
An excerpt of the plot taken from Wikipedia

Set during the Mexico Revolution of the 1910s, the film tells the story of Juan Miranda (Steiger), an amoral Mexican outlaw, and John Mallory (Coburn), an ex-Irish Republican revolutionary. After they accidentally meet under less-than-friendly circumstances, Juan and John involuntarily become heroes of the Revolution despite being forced to make heavy sacrifices.

